# PHP wkhtmltopdf issue with ChartJS

Tags: php, chart.js, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the PHP wrapper for Wkhtmltopdf available here https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf to convert an HTML page that has some ChartJS code.

My PHP code works with one ChartJS code and it generates a PDF but with a second code, the graph is missing.

Below is my PHP code:

```php
$path_to_pdf = ROOT . FOLDER_APP . '/PDF/Graph2.pdf';
$pdf = new mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf($html);
$pdf->setOptions(array(
    'orientation' => 'landscape'
));
$pdf->binary = ROOT . FOLDER_APP . '/wkhtmltox/wkhtmltox_0.12.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
if (!$pdf->saveAs($path_to_pdf)) {
    echo $pdf->getError();
}
```

The `$html` variable holds the HTML code.

If I use [this HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/dorfLpxu/1/) it works:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/960gs/0/960.css" />
  <title>OCA-Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  table th{
  text-align: center;
  }
  .px{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -21px;
  font-size: 11px;
  }
  .shadow{
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 279px;
  height: 115px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  width: 952px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  color: transparent;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container_12">
  <div class="shadow">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <span style="margin-left: 60px;float: left;">stabil</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 49px;float: left;">glücklich</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 43px;float: left;">ruhig</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 42px;float: left;">Gewissheit</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 37px;float: left;">aktiv</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 48px;float: left;">energisch</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 31px;float: left;">ursächlich</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 21px;float: left;">korrekte<br>Einschätzung</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 15px;float: left;">wert<br>-schätzend</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 15px;float: left;">Kommunika-<br>tionsniveau</span>
  </div>
  <p class="px" style="margin-top: 161px;">Wün-<br>schens-<br>wert</p>
  <p class="px" style="margin-top: 297px;">Normal</p>
  <p class="px" style="margin-top: 322px;">unakzep-<br>tabler</p>
  <p class="px" style="margin-top: 369px;">Zustand</p>
  <canvas id="linechart"></canvas>
  <div>
  <span style="margin-left: 76px;">A</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 76px;">B</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 76px;">C</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 76px;">D</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 76px;">E</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 80px;">F</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 80px;">G</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 80px;">H</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 80px;">I</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 80px;">J</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span style="margin-left: 60px;float: left;">instabil<br>zerstreut</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 28px;float: left;">deprimiert</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 34px;float: left;">nervös</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 32px;float: left;">Unsicherheit</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 26px;float: left;">untätig</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 40px;float: left;">gehemmt</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 27px;float: left;">verant-<br>wortungslos</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 31px;float: left;">kritisch</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 31px;float: left;">Mangel an<br>Übere-<br>instimmung</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 28px;float: left;">zurück-<br>gezogen</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var linedata = {
  datasets: [{
  fill: false,
  lineTension: 0,
  borderColor: "black",
  borderWidth: [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
  pointBackgroundColor: ["blue", "blue","blue", "blue","blue", "blue","blue", "blue","blue", "blue"],
  pointRadius: [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
  pointStyle: ["rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect","rect"],
  data: [
  {x: 0.25, y: 80},
  {x: 0.75, y: -14},
  {x: 1.25, y: -46},
  {x: 1.75, y: 30},
  {x: 2.25, y: 14},
  {x: 2.75, y: -20},
  {x: 3.25, y: -72},
  {x: 3.75, y: -56},
  {x: 4.25, y: -24},
  {x: 4.75, y: -52}
  ]
  }]
  };
  var chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  legend: {display: false},
  gridLines :{

  },
  scales: {
  yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
  beginAtZero: false,
  max: 100,
  min: -100
  }
  }],
  xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
  display: false
  }
  }]
  }
  };
  var lineID = document.getElementById("linechart").getContext("2d");
  var lineChart = new Chart(lineID, {
  type: "scatter",
  data: linedata,
  options: chartOptions
  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if I use [this HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/w7e8sug0/), the PDF does not show the graph:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>OCA-Test</title>
        <style>
            .grey {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }
            .dark {
                background-color: #888;
            }
            .pink{
                background-color: #e4b9c0;
            }
            .square {
                height: 20px;
                width: 150px;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
                <p>Oxford capacity analysis<p>
                <p style="line-height:0.5;">Bea Ahlers<p>
                <p>16/10/1983</p>
            </div>
            <div style="line-height: 0.6;float:right;display:inline-block;">
                <p style="text-align:right;">Urgently needs attention:<span class="square grey"></span></p>
                <p style="text-align:right;">Requires attention:<span class="square dark"></span></p>
                <p style="text-align:right;">Acceptable under perfect condition:<span class="square pink"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <canvas id="chartJSContainer" style="height:800px;"></canvas>
            <script>
    const labels = ["stable","happy","composed","certainty","active","aggressive",["responsible","causativ"],["correct","estimation"],"appreciative",["communication","level"]];
    const labels2 = [["unstable,","dispersed"],"depressed","nervous","uncertainty","inactiv","inhibited","irresponsible","critical",["lack","of","accord"],"withdrawn"];
    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "",
          data: [-92, -100, -99, -86, 8, 56, -94, -89, -92, -24],
          borderColor: "transparent",
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          order: 1
        },
        {
          label: "",
          data: [-92, -100, -99, -86, 8, 56, -94, -89, -92, -24],
          borderColor: "black",
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          type: "line",
          borderWidth: 2,
          order: 0
        }
      ]
    };
    const config = {
      type: "bar",
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          title: {
            display: false
          },
          backgrounds: {
                hbars: [{
                    from: -100,
                    to: -22,
                    color: "rgb(228, 185, 192)"
                  },
                  {
                    from: -22,
                    to: 0,
                    color: "rgb(136, 136, 136)"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 30,
                    color: "rgb(221, 221, 221)"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            min: -100,
            max: 100
          },
          x: {
            position: "bottom",
            grid: {
              offset: true
            }
          },
          x2: {
            position: "top",
            grid: {
              offset: true
            },
            labels: labels2
          }
        },
        plugins: [{
    id: "backgrounds",
    beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea,
        scales
      } = chart;
      const y = scales.y;
      options.hbars.forEach((hBar) => {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
        ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from), chartArea.right - chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.to) - y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from));
        ctx.restore();
      });
    }
  }]  
    };
    var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chartJSContainer"), config);
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not seeing any error in `echo $pdf->getError();`

Comment: What debugging have you done? Seems like first step would be to load that HTML into a browser and check JS console for errors.

Comment: Also, don't wrap an entire HTML document in quotes, it's just asking for trouble. Use a [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead

Comment: Yes, I tried in JS console an I found no errors, here is links to each page: https://jsfiddle.net/dorfLpxu/1/   https://jsfiddle.net/w7e8sug0/

Comment: I'm sure you didn't put actual patient data in your sample charts, right?

Comment: Can you try setting this option in addition:`$pdf->setOptions(['orientation' => 'landscape', 'debug_javascript']);`  and then after you create the PDF, try `echo $pdf->getCommand()->getOutput();`. After a quick look at the code, it seems like it should work to show some debugging output for JS.

Comment: Sorry, meant `$pdf->setOptions(['orientation' => 'landscape', 'debug-javascript']);` with hyphen, not underscore.

Comment: Actually, I notice the second HTML has a doctype header. Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: Yes I noticed that and I have the Doctype in my test page and it still does not work. I tried your code for debugging JS but it showed noting. Could it be related to javascript-delay because the first texts above the graph show but not the graph. Could it be that it needs time to render the JS code?

Comment: You could certainly try setting that `javascript-delay` option as well; default is 200ms, you could try setting to 5000 or something. I'm not sure why you'd get no output from `debug-javascript` option. You could also try running from command line and see if you get anything useful. `echo $pdf->getCommand()->getExecCommand();` should show you the command line it's running.

Comment: $pdf->getCommand()->getOutput(); give empty string and $pdf->getCommand()->getExecCommand(); gives /home/xxxx/public_html/OCA-Test/wkhtmltox/wkhtmltox_0.12.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf '--orientation' 'landscape' '--javascript-delay' '5000' '/tmp/tmp_wkhtmlto_pdf_hm7Pvn.html' '/tmp/tmp_wkhtmlto_pdf_VQYaqh.pdf'

Comment: Here is my code **bold** $path_to_pdf = ROOT . FOLDER_APP . '/PDF/Graph3.pdf';
$pdf = new mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf($html);
$pdf->setOptions(
    [
        'orientation' => 'landscape', 
        'javascript-delay' => 5000
    ]
  );
$pdf->binary = ROOT . FOLDER_APP . '/wkhtmltox/wkhtmltox_0.12.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
if (!$pdf->saveAs($path_to_pdf)) {
    echo $pdf->getError();
}else{
     var_dump($pdf->getCommand()->getOutput());
     var_dump($pdf->getCommand()->getExecCommand());
} **bold**

Comment: Yes, getOutput should be empty without the debug setting. So what happens if you run the command from CLI? Any hints? `/home/xxxx/public_html/OCA-Test/wkhtmltox/wkhtmltox_0.12.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf '--orientation' 'landscape' '--javascript-delay' '5000' 'debug-javascript' 'input_html_file.html' 'output_pdf_file.pdf'`

Comment: I don't have wkhtmltopdf installed, I have it located in a folder and I use it with that PHP wrapper. I'm not sure it will work from command line.